# How to use more than 2 I2S microphones on MKR Zero?

Tags: sound, mkr1000

I am trying to build a portable device that can record from at least 3 microphones. I had a look and saw I2S is good for audio so I bought an Arduino MKR Zero to read them with. I was wondering how to record from multiple microphones on the I2S bus at once. The only thing that I have been able to do is record stereo from two mics but I need the microphone readings to be mono. I am using the Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone SPH0645LM4H.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the I2S bus only allows up to 2 channels to be transmitted at the same time.  Here is a quote from the [Details section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S#Details) of the Wikipedia's [I2S page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S):

> The word select clock lets the device know whether channel 0 or
>   channel 1 is currently being sent, because I²S allows two channels to
>   be sent on the same data line.

This is further illustrated in Figure 8 / Page 6 of the [Knowles SPH0645LM4H data specifications](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Knowles%20Acoustics%20PDFs/SPH0645LM4H-B.pdf).  In this figure we see where 2 SPH0645LM4H microphones are configured (ground or Vcc to the SEL pin 2) such that they can be multiplexed onto the I2S bus by the I2S bus master.